# jQuery: trigger() on a link

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, jquery-events, eventtrigger, rel

I am trying to `trigger()` a link but it does not seem to work.

An `<img>` element has a `rel` attribute that contains the id of the link.
Clicking on the element should trigger the corresponding link if possible.

I think the problem is that I'm capturing a jQuery click event rather than the native link action.

Anyway, here is the code for you to see:

```
$("#contentmenu li a").click(function(e){
    switch(e.target.id){
        case "opt1":
            alert('do something');
        break;
        case "opt2":
            alert('do something');
        break;
        case "opt3":
            alert('do something');
        break;
    }
    //return false;
});

$("#box_content img").click(function(e){
    menuItem=$(this).attr('rel');
    $('#'+menuItem).trigger('click');
    //return false;
});
```

**EDIT**

I found my answer: It is not possible to trigger the link's native event this way
so I will resort to using `window.location` instead.

Comment: Try logging the target.id, what do you get?

Comment: it is working fine..check th example http://jsfiddle.net/sbJHR/

Comment: @Richard this is old post but curios to know what happened ? how it was solved ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#YourLinkId')[0].click();
```

I have Tested on IE9, IE8 and Chrome.
**This works on IE , but doesn't work on Chrome !**